# Hook D8's Search API query to filter results by field from session or parameter values

Tags: 8, entities, search

I am using Search API with a simple database server to index a relatively small amount of data from 3 content types.

I'd like to offer users a separate select field to further filter search results and fallback on a session value when omitted.

How can I hook the search API query to set a field filter value?